# BASH: alternatives to coproc

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

I have some scripts which use [coproc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html) to control stdout/stdin of subprocesses.
Unfortunately, coproc was introduced in Bash 4.0, and on many systems I use, there is an earlier versions of bash.

Are there any alternatives to coproc?

Comment: Bash has a lot more severe, unexplained limitations as well. I think, you are on the point when you should leave it and use some other (maybe perl or python were good choices in your place).

Comment: @PeterHorvath, that is true, but bash is the only "language" which is common for all platforms. I try to write my script for the common denominator rather than maintaining different versions of it.

Comment: Perl also exists everywhere. And you can see, that also bash isn't really uniform everywhere.

Comment: -bash: perl: command not found

Comment: You have right, I am really sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can used standard `named pipe` instead of `coproc`:

```
mkfifo in_data out_data

command <in_data >out_data &

exec 3> in_data 4< out_data

echo <some thing here> >&3
read <some variables here> <&4
```

Comment: Warning: This works, but is surprisingly buffered. All the tricks like `stdbuf -o0 {bash_script}` to disable this buffering, rely on external tools that are generally only available on Linux.